# C# Convert enum to char

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

So I have an enum like this:

```
enum element
{
    Side = '|', Top = '-', Corner = '.'
}
```

And then I have a two-dimensional char array which only contains the chars | - .

But when I try to write:

```
array[2, 3] = element.Side;
```

I get an error saying that  "cannot implicitly convert type element to 'char'"

So... What do I do wrong? Is there an elegant way for me to turn my two-dimensional char array into an array containing the corresponding enums? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: `array[2, 3] = (char)element.Side;` cast the enum to `char`

Comment: Please edit the title to say enum to char instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to cast the `element.Side` to a char:

```
arr[2, 3] = (char)element.Side
```

> Why you should do this?

*The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type that consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list.*

*Every enumeration type has an underlying type, **which can be any integral type** **except char**. The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int. To declare an enum of another integral type, such as byte, use a colon after the identifier followed by the type, as shown in the following example.*

> So what is happening by declaring your enum?

Under the cover, the compiler produces for each character of your enum it's correspoding integral representation. You could verify this, by creating a console application and trying to write to the console the following:

```
(int)element.Side
```

You will get 124. Please check [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/) to verify that 124 is the decimal representation of vertical bar.

Furthermore, you could verify this by using a dissasembler. The picture below has been taken using IL DASM.

[image]

If you click at the `Side: public static literal...` a new window would be opened with the following statement.

[image]

What is 0x0000007C?

The Hexadecimal representation of vertical bar !
You could find further info on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

You could find further info regarding `enum` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have `char` as your base type of an enum, therefore, it is not possible to implicitly convert an `element` to a `char`. Although you have given `char` values to the elements in your enum, they are converted to their `int` values. You have to cast before you use them:

```
arr[2, 3] = (char)element.Side
```

So actually, your code is:

```
enum element : int
{
    Side = '|', Top = '-', Corner = '.'
}
```

And if you try to set your base type to a `char`, the compiler will complain.